# Git diff not listing specific changes to files?

Tags: git

I've been playing around with adding and committing, and using `diff` to show discrepancies between the HEAD, index, and working dir. Using `diff`, my understanding is that it is supposed to specify which files have changed, but also it is supposed to specify the differences between files (eg. if I write "hello" into a file, it should say `+hello` (or something similar) when I run `diff` and it compares the two).

When I use `diff`, however, it only shows me that a file has changed; it fails to show what those changes are. Why isn't it showing the individual changes in files -- the actual text that I've added, what specifically I've deleted, etc.? If `diff` does not do this, is there a command I can use for it?

Thank you.

---

To run a full test, I deleted `.git` and ran a `git-init`, then found `diff` did not show diff for all three variations of `diff` (`git diff`, `git diff --cached`, and `git diff HEAD`). The file I used is `t.txt`. This is my console, which I formatted for readability; `>>` is where Powershell prompts for input, which I typed into the console; comments were written as I went, denoted with `>> # <comment>`. This is my console output:

```
>> # Starting with nothing.

>> git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

>> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/q/Documents/GitHub/.git/

>> ls

>> git status
On branch master
Initial commit
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

>> echo "New file created." > t.txt

>> git status
On branch master
Initial commit
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        t.txt
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)


>> git add .

>> git status
On branch master
Initial commit
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   t.txt


>> #open t.txt and add a second line of text to it

>> git status
On branch master
Initial commit
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
       new file:   t.txt
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   t.txt


>> git diff
diff --git a/t.txt b/t.txt
index e7a4f8a..fe91a49 100644
Binary files a/t.txt and b/t.txt differ

>> #How can I see the exact change?
>> #Something like: '''
>> #
>> # + This is the added line.
>> #
>> # ''' in the diff?


>> # I can take this even further by making the first commit, modifying, then staging the file 
                              # with `git add`, then editing again, and then run all three `git-diff`s 
                              # (git diff, git diff --cached, git diff HEAD) and none of them will specify any actual 
                              # changes in the files; Git still just lists the files that have discrepancies, without 
                              # listing any of the detials about /what/ is actually different.


>> git add .

>> git commit -m "Committed with the second line."
[master (root-commit) 14acc45] Committed with the second line.
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 t.txt

>> git diff

>> git log
commit 14acc455b16ba26cdea1661166b0ffc3fa089784
Author: q <q@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Nov 7 04:29:20 2015 -0800
    Committed with the second line.

>> git diff HEAD

>> git diff HEAD^
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'


>> #We change the file again to add a third line


>> git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   t.txt
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")


>> git diff
diff --git a/t.txt b/t.txt
index fe91a49..006c33a 100644
Binary files a/t.txt and b/t.txt differ


>> git diff HEAD
diff --git a/t.txt b/t.txt
index fe91a49..006c33a 100644
Binary files a/t.txt and b/t.txt differ


>> git add .

>> #Modify file again.

>> git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   t.txt
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   t.txt


>> git diff
diff --git a/t.txt b/t.txt
index 006c33a..57a6754 100644
Binary files a/t.txt and b/t.txt differ

>> git diff HEAD
diff --git a/t.txt b/t.txt
index fe91a49..57a6754 100644
Binary files a/t.txt and b/t.txt differ

>> git diff --cached
diff --git a/t.txt b/t.txt
index fe91a49..006c33a 100644
Binary files a/t.txt and b/t.txt differ

>>## But how do they differ?
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15009104/1517864), to treat binary files as text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file is too small, git doesn't know how to interpret it (test or binary): see "[Why does Git treat this text file as a binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6856566/6309)"

You can force a text diff with:

```
git diff --text
```

(or you can [configure it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19723302/6309) as text)

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. By the way, thanks for including that link about configuring Git to treat it as text -- one of the answers says that not saving in UTF-8 will mess up the first 8000 blocks or something .... anyway, I checked and `echo "HI" > t.txt` saves to Unicode. Opening notepad -> Save as... -> UTF-8 made the problem go away entirely!