# Force Git to read ANSI files containing NUL

Tags: git, character-encoding, nul

There are many, many places describing how to "force" Git to read a file as text. Generally, the solution involves adding a filter to `.gitattributes` to apply the `text` attribute to the file(s). Examples include:

```
* text
* text=auto
* text diff merge
* text=auto diff merge
```

But this solution seems to not work if the file contains NUL. Here is an example file text file with ANSI encoding and trailing null bytes:

[image]

It's completely readable as a text file, just not by Git. Every example filter above will fail and Git will identify as "binary" regardless. I think this is due to its hard-coded check for NUL in the first 8000 characters ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19723302)).

Of course, as soon as I convert the file to UTF-8 Git happily identifies it as text. Here is that same file after conversion:

[image]

Frankly I don't mind *not* using ANSI encoding. I'm just trying to avoid constantly opening files in Notepad++ just to fix the file encoding. Is there a way to make Git handle the encoding conversion automatically?

Comment: There is no major single-byte encoding (whether so-called "ANSI" or not) where NUL is anything other than a NUL.  The same byte is also a NUL in UTF-8.  Your tool is actually stripping these characters incorrectly when converting them to UTF-8.  And this is by definition not a text file, since NUL is never valid in a text file, according to POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems here.  The first is that these are definitely *not* text files, since they contain a NUL byte.  No major single-byte encoding permits NUL bytes to represent anything other than a NUL because C terminates its strings with that byte, and using it for another purpose would mean that text in that encoding would not fit into a normal C string.  POSIX specifically excludes files containing NUL bytes from being text files for this reason.

The tool you're using to convert your “ANSI” files to UTF-8 is actually *stripping out the NUL bytes*, which is why they then work.  The NUL byte in UTF-8 means exactly the same thing as it does in your single-byte encoding: a NUL.  So this works because your tool is stripping them out instead of properly converting them.

It also isn't clear what you're asking Git to do in this case.  The `text` attribute asks Git to perform end-of-line normalization.  However, if your file contains NUL bytes, then Git is still going to think it's a binary file for the purposes of diffs and merge, because the `text` attribute doesn't control that.  You need the `diff` and `merge` attributes as well.

Of course, if you don't really want or need the NUL bytes and these are supposed to be human-readable, then you really are better off just stripping out the NUL bytes and converting to UTF-8.  In 2020, there's no longer any good reason to use a single-byte encoding.  If that's what you want to do, then you can strip the NUL bytes and convert to UTF-8 by doing the following (assuming you're using Git Bash, WSL, or a Linux system):

```
$ tr -d '\0' FILENAME | iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8 > FILENAME.tmp && \
  mv FILENAME.tmp FILENAME
```

That also assumes that the “ANSI” encoding you're using is actually Windows-1252.  IANA (the register of character sets) doesn't know of any encodings called “ANSI”, but Windows-1252 is the most common character set referred to that way.

Finally, you can specify a working tree encoding with the `working-tree-encoding` value in `gitattributes` if you absolutely must handle non-UTF-8 files.  That isn't going to fix your NUL problem, though, and UTF-8 is a better choice in almost all situations.

Comment: No.No. NULL is permitted in most encoding, and it is not the C terminated string. C choose such convention, and it was also called ASCIIZ. Other protocols just use new line as terminating (or a specific escape). Pascal, Python (and many other languages) allow you to have NULL in a string, and it is ok for ASCII strings. There are UTF-8 encodings (not official from Unicode, but compatible) which allow NULL in string, and `\0` to terminate a string.

Comment: I'm not arguing about any language other than C.  I'm fully aware that NUL is allowed in many languages' strings.  It is, however, [prohibited in text files by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html), and I stand by my statement that no major single-byte encoding uses the zero bytes as anything other than NUL.

Comment: ASCII allow NULL. The question is not about POSIX (nobody will use "ANSI" for an encoding in POSIX), and the language in question is not C (but if one use `#define If if` and so on). Linux use null (e.g. in `/proc`, as field separator (the rest is text), and `git` is not just about text files (in posix definition, in facts, it allows different end of line characters).

Comment: I fully understand how Git works in this case and that it can handle any kind of files; I'm a core contributor.  The generally understood definition of "text file" (contrasted with "binary file") excludes bytes with NUL; using a standard definition, such as POSIX, to define the term "text file" is entirely reasonable.  For example, `file` would call these files “data” because they contain NUL, not “text”; see the manual page for details.

Comment: @bk2204 `file` apparently considers files with an odd number of `NUL` characters data `printf 'foo\0 | file -` -> `data` but even number `ascii` `printf 'foo\0\0' | file -` ‍♂️